# Ainda existe motivo para usar var em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, declaração-de-variável

O ES6 introduziu as keywords `let` e `const` para declaração de variáveis.

Ainda existe motivo para utilizar `var`? Se sim, em que cenários utilizar?

Comment: leia http://www.matera.com/br/2017/05/09/javascript-6-diferenca-entre-var-let-e-const/

Answer (score 2):

Bem, fazendo uma breve pesquisa na internet, inclusive no SOen, não há vantagem declarada. Até então, `let` e `const` oferecem de certa forma uma certa 'proteção, por seguir regras' a mais do que o `var`, mas fazem o mesmo trabalho.

Para não dizer nenhuma vantagem, alguns navegadores ainda não aceitam a declaração de `let` e `const`, mas fora isso, o `var` já pode ser aposentado.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable